# Python - Removing duplicate nested lists from a dictionary after first element

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am using the code beneath to scan through a dictionary and remove duplicate lists.

```
nduplicates = {k:[list(y) for y in {tuple(x[1:]) for x in v}] for k,v in resulsts.items()}
```

The dictionary `results` is in this format:

```
{'example': [['london','5.123', '-3.123'],['bham','5.123', '-3.123'],['manc','51.23', '-3.453']], [etc..]}
```

Applying the list comprehension works and removes the duplicate nested lists, exclusing the first element; leaving the dictionary like this:

```
{'example': [['london','5.123', '-3.123'],['manc','51.23', '-3.453']]}
```

I was wondering if there is a different way to go about removing the duplicates opposed to the already working solution. I have also tried, but this isn't fully working anyway:

```
print({k: [y for x, y in enumerate(v) \
     if y not in v[1:x]] for k, v in results.items()})
```

Thanks for any help! Any other work arounds for the list comprehension/remove duplicate code would be appreciated!

Comment: The list comprehension over the set produces lists **without** the first element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah thanks! Is there an easy way to go back and include the first element?

Comment: You can have any number of first elements, there isn't just one possible first element here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a way to say, if a duplicate is found, keep the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my codes:

```
def remove_dup(my_lst):
    from copy import deepcopy
    from collections import OrderedDict
    my_lst = list(reversed(deepcopy(my_lst)))

    ordred_dict = OrderedDict()

    for sub_list in my_lst:
        ordred_dict[tuple(sub_list[1:])] = sub_list

    return list(ordred_dict.values())


def main():
    results = {'example': [['london', '5.123', '-3.123'], ['bham', '5.123', '-3.123'], ['manc', '51.23', '-3.453']]}
    nduplicates = {k: remove_dup(v) for k, v in results.items()}
    print(nduplicates)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and you got:

```
{'example': [['manc', '51.23', '-3.453'], ['london', '5.123', '-3.123']]}
```

The codes about reverse the list guarantees that if a duplicate is found, keep the first element.